# Material UI Confirm Alert is hidden behind dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, alert

I have a material ui dialog that has the user confirm an action. The problem is the alert is hidden behind the dialog. Is there a way to give the alert a higher z index or something in order to avoid this so that the alert would take the foreground?

```
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { confirmAlert } from "react-confirm-alert";

<Dialog><Button onClick={clickEvent}</Button></Dialog>

function clickEvent(){
    await confirmAlert({
        title: "title",
        message: "message",
        buttons: [
          {
            label: "ok",
          },
          {
            label: "cancel",
          },
        ],
      });
    }
}
```

As a work around i could have dialog close on click event and then reopen again. Would rather be able to just have the alert take the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overlayClassName option on confirmAlert component for put z-index.
Here is an example:

Css:

```
.overlay-custom-class-name {
    z-index: 101;
}
```

React:

```
  confirmAlert({
          title: 'Test Title',
          message: 'Question',
          buttons: [
            {
              label: 'Yes',
              onClick: () => this.function()
            },
            {
              label: 'No'
            }
          ],
          overlayClassName: "overlay-custom-class-name" --Put your css Class
        });
```

Comment: I have to set zIndex value = 9999 to place the confirm alert on top of material UI drawer/modal.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set "zIndex: 99999" in the MUI Alert sx={{}} for it to be in front of the MUI Dialog.   9999 was not high enough, so keep increasing it until it is.

Answer (score 0):

today in MUI I see Dialog has z-index: 1300
so I set 1301 for Alert from sx prop.

```
<Alert sx={{zIndex: '1301'}}>
  {alertData.text}
</Alert>
```